# Why the second term is transposed, but not the first one?

Tags: variance, expected-value, matrix

I am not very good at maths. I just have this silly question. Why do I have to transpose the second term in expectation?

I mean why $Var(X) = E[(x−μ)(x−μ)^T)]$ and not this $E[(x−μ)^T(x−μ))]$ ?

Comment: You can't multiply matrices in any order -- they must have specific dimensions. You can right multiply a 1 x 2 matrix by a 2 x 4 matrix, but you can't right multiply a 2 x 4 matrix by a 1 x 2 matrix. Similarly, if you have an n x p vector, you can't multiply it by an n x p vector-- you have to transpose one if you want to right multiply, so you end up with n x p * p x n.

Comment: It's nothing to do with expectation *per se*, it has to do with what you want to calculate the expectation *of*. You can take both $E[(x−μ)(x−μ)^T)]$ and  $E[(x−μ)^T(x−μ))]$ but only one of them is the variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: What is $X$? a random matrix? a little tip to get better at maths: define as much of your notation as possible! it's not just so others will understand what you write. it's also so you yourself will understand! i think once you realise $X$ is a random matrix, then that will be at least helpful if you don't get the whole answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the convention that $(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})$ is a column vector, i.e.  $(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) = \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} - \mu_1\\
           x_{2} - \mu_2\\
           \vdots \\
           x_{m}- \mu_m
         \end{bmatrix}$, then $(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T$ is a row vector, i.e $(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T= [x_{1} - \mu_1, x_{2} - \mu_2,\dots ,x_{m} - \mu_m]$.
The product of a column vector and a row vector forms a matrix with the corresponding pairwise products as entries. The product of a row vector and a column vector (the dot product) results in the sum of the pairwise products.

Since your $Var(X)$ is a variance-covariance **matrix**, you need to have the product of a column vector and a row vector, i.e. $(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T$.

Answer (score 6):

When you multiply matrices, the adjacent dimensions need to match, so you can multiply the (n, k) matrix by (k, m) matrix, or (m, k) by (k, n), but not any other way around. Where you would see the transpose symbol it depends on if the data is stored row-wise or column-wise. If you take something like a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of row vectors, you would transpose the second element so you multiply (1, n) by (n, 1), but if the data had the initial shape of (n, 1), you would do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

For any column vector $x$ (eg $x \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$)

1. $x^Tx$ is (a 1x1 matrix and thus 'is isomorphic to' (*)) a scalar.
2. $xx^T$ is a matrix. (and if it's 1x1, then it could be treated as a scalar similarly.)

(*) in your case 'is isomorphic to' just means 'can be treated as'

Comment: I believe it's important to be clear in one's explanation when responding to elementary math questions like this, so that additional confusion isn't created.

Comment: @whuber i would do that in maths se. i wasn't really sure stats se had similar standards of rigour. i'm very please to know that stats se does.

Comment: I'm suggesting this isn't a matter of rigor so much as it concerns making your explanations as clear as possible.

Comment: @whuber ah well thanks for your opinion. but in my opinion, i was clear just not rigorous.  my aim for the answer was to be more succinct than the others. i figured my lack of rigour (or clarity) is partly based on that i had others that came before. i wouldn't submit my original answer as a 1st answer.

Comment: @whuber also does one really not need to say like $x \in R^{n \times 1}$ for some ring $R$ or what? i'll edit